# Software Index is broken error and configuring Secure Boot pop-up

Tags: package-management, uefi, update-manager

Ok so I am getting this Software index is broken error. The complete error is as following -

```
Software Index is broken. 
It is impossible to install or remove any software. 
Please use the software manager "Synaptic" 
or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a terminal to fix the issue at first.
```

When I run the synaptic package manager, I get this -

```
An error occurred The following details are provided
E:dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. E:_cache->open() failed, please report.
```

When I ran the Software Updater, this popped out -

```
Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled

UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with third-party drivers.
The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. 
To permit the use of third-party drivers, 
a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been generated. 
This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.

To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user, 
and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now 
and then confirm the change after reboot using the same password, 
in both the "Enroll MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus 
that will be presented to you when this system reboots.

If you proceed but do not confirm the password upon reboot, 
Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your system 
but any hardware that requires third-party drivers to work correctly may not be usable.
```

Software index is broken error:

[image: Image of Software index is broken error]

Synaptic Package Manager error:

[image: Synaptic Package Manager error]

UEFI Secure boot pop-up:

[image: UEFI Secure boot Pop up]

Distro - Ubuntu 22.04

Laptop - Acer Aspire 7, Ryzen 7 3750h, GTX 1650

From what I remember, I had an issue where my screen was not shared after connecting the laptop with HDMI and I was looking for answers I might have run  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but I honestly do not remember.

What exactly should I do now?